# GWT WebApp finding entry point

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

I'm having a maven project with 3 module: api, gwt, web.

the web module create the war file now I'm having 2 gwt.xml files

client.gwt.xml,  from my gwt-module.It implements the views, presenter, entrypoint

```
<module>

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT' />

    <!--Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='com.myapp.admin.client.EntryPoint'/>    

    <source path='rest'/>
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='consts'/>

</module>
```

and web.gwt.xml, from my web-module, where the app should be deployed. It inherits the gwt module as you can see com.myapp.admin.client.

```
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

<inherits name='com.myapp.admin.client' />
```

I also added a dependency in my pom.xml with the module. But I'm missing some inherit because:

```
Compiling module com.myapp.admin.web
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.myapp.admin.client.EntryPoint
         [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'com.myapp.admin.client.EntryPoint'
         [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
```

I can follow the trace and I understand why there is no class path in com.myapp.admin.client because when I build my module only the classes from my web module are build. but I thougt with the dependency and the inherits its enough. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT: POM.xml WEB**

```
        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>

    </plugin>


    <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

**POM.xml client**

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet your `client` jar doesn't include the *.java source files. GWT needs both compiled classes and source files (primarily source files).

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/library.html

Comment: added the part of my pom.xml, so the main goal is to change the <goals> to resource that I can get also my source files (if thats right).

Comment: You need to add a call to the `resources` goal of the `gwt-maven-plugin` (I prefer just configuring `src/main/java` as a `<resource>` BTW) **in the _client_ module** (alternatively, if you `source:jar-no-fork` there, you can also simply add the `<type>java-source</type>` dependency on the _client_ module in addition to the `<type>jar</type>` one)

Comment: ok perfect, know my file compiles but when i try to run it somehow my app tries to find [WARN] 404 - GET /client/client.nocache.js (127.0.0.1) instead of /web/web.nocache.js (found in target) why is that? namespace client.* came from client.gwt.xml i guess but how?

Comment: Look at your HTML host page; I'd bet it contains `<script src="client/client.nocache.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="web/web.nocache.js"></script>`.